Orthogonal Basis in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$
This problem is part of my study on orthogonal functions and their role in $L^2$ spaces. Understanding the construction of orthogonal bases is crucial in fields like quantum mechanics, where such functions are used to describe states.
Define the following:
$$
X_j f(x) := x_j f(x), \quad D_j f(x) := \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_j}
$$
$$
L_j := \frac{X_j + D_j}{2}, \quad U_j := \frac{X_j - D_j}{2}
$$
$$
U^\alpha := \prod_{j=1}^d U_j^{\alpha_j}, \quad L^\alpha := \prod_{j=1}^d L_j^{\alpha_j}
$$
$$
f_0(x) := e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{2}}, \quad f^\alpha := U^\alpha f_0
$$
(a) Show that the collection $\{f^\alpha\}_{0 \leq |\alpha| < \infty}$ forms an orthogonal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
(b) Find the sets $S_j$ for $j \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ such that $S_j = (-i)^j I$, and $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d) = S_0 \oplus S_1 \oplus S_2 \oplus S_3$.
For part (a), my initial approach is to start by explicitly calculating the inner products between the functions $f^\alpha$ and using the properties of the operators $U_j$ and $L_j$ to establish orthogonality. Specifically, I plan to show that for different multi-indices $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the inner product $\langle f^\alpha, f^\beta \rangle = 0$ unless $\alpha = \beta$. This involves verifying that the operators $U_j$ and $L_j$ behave in a way that preserves orthogonality when applied to the Gaussian function $f_0(x)$.
To prove this, I will use the fact that the Gaussian function $f_0(x) = e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{2}}$ has nice properties under differentiation and multiplication by polynomials, which should simplify the calculation of the inner products.
Would this method be the right approach to proving the orthogonality of the functions $f^\alpha$? If there’s a more efficient method or if I should consider additional properties, I would appreciate your guidance.

This is precisely what is asked in (a). Please edit your post to show some attempt.

It seems showing orthogonality will be much easier than showing it forms a basis for $L^2$. +1 since I’m really looking forward to seeing the answers!

explained at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions

Instead of repeating that you are "planning to" calculate $\langle f^\alpha, f^\beta \rangle$, better do it, and include this calculation in your post.
